# DISPATCH_QUEUE_T in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm programming my first Swift 3 but I came across the following error

**dispatch_queue_t is unavailable in swift.**

```
var queue: dispatch_queue_t?

var debugPrint = false

public init() {
    let uuid = NSUUID().uuidString
    let queueLabel = "tomlogger-queue-" + uuid
    queue = dispatch_queue_create(queueLabel, DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)

}
```

Does anyone know how I solve this error,

Thomas

Comment: The Xcode migrator (Edit -> Convert -> To current Swift syntax) fixes that automatically.

Answer (score 15):

You need to use `DispatchQueue` instead, libdispatch was modernised to match the swift 3 syntax, see the proposal [SE-0088](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0088-libdispatch-for-swift3.md)